# SPARQL timestamp to date

Tags: sparql, rdf, virtuoso

I have an RDF file uploaded in a Virtuoso RDF Store. The RDF contains sensor measurements extracted from a Relational DB, with the following format:

```
TIMESTAMP  | DEVICE_ID  | VALUE
1454688000 | device_125 | 25.3
```

RDF snippet:

```
<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://example.org#device_125">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://example.org#device"/>
    <ont1:hasValue rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">25.3<ont1:hasValue />
    <ont1:hasTimestamp rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#long">1454688000<ont1:hasTimestamp/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
```

Time concepts are in timestamp, and I would like to know if I can convert them to dateTime format, using SPARQL capabilities.

For example, having this timestamp: `1454688000`, convert it into this date (or similar format): `Fri, 05 Feb 2016 14:00:00 GMT`

I am aware that SPARQL lets you do some arithmetical operations, but not sure if this can be done.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: It's not clear what you're actually starting from, so providing appropriate advice is difficult-to-impossible. Can you show us a more complete snippet of sample data? Turtle is usually the best format for such.

Comment: @TallTed for me, the question looks like: How to use SPARQL to convert a timestamp (probably `xsd:long`) to a date type (probably `xsd:dateTime`). The rest looks more like rendering of date values, which doesn't exist in SPARQL but any client side API can do.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your starting point and goal correctly, you should be able to do something like this, using standard SPARQL --

```
SELECT                             ?deviceid
       xsd:dateTime(?timestamp) AS ?eventtime
                                   ?value
WHERE 
  {  ?deviceid  ont1:hasTimestamp  ?timestamp  ;
                ont1:hasValue      ?value
  }
```

Virtuoso has other features that may be helpful (including the ability to convert from `xsd:dateTime` to formatted `xsd:string`), but these step outside of standard SPARQL.